# Telegram bot - How can I create a popup message?

Tags: telegram-bot

Thanks for reaching this feed.

I would like to request the method/example/API doc for the popup "Spin Wheel" (see below image) in the [Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots#payment-platform) doc.

I have tried a couple of keywords e.g. telegram bot custom popup, but still no luck..

Thanks for your time!

[image]

https://core.telegram.org/bots#payment-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think now you can do similar custom controlls with telegram web apps feature:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted

Comment: @xcHades Thanks a lot! Just saw your answer and realized this is a Telegram Update 2 days ago. Here is the [link at April-16-2022](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#april-16-2022) for the announcement of the webapp feature!